Code for q-v diagram and desired speed distribution
I have received several traffic data over a certain period of time as a CSV file. The columns are Speed, Time, Date, Direction, Length and Time Gap. I now need a q-v diagram in a 15-minute interval and then the desired speed distribution (as a root function according to HBS) as a normal distribution compared to the normal distribution of the unaffected vehicles. The distributions should be calculated using least squares estimation. The method is based on the methods of Hoogendorn and Geistefeldt. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the Python code to work the way it should and need help.
My current Python code looks like this, the code does not have to correspond completely to Hoogendorn's or Geistefeldt's method, but it does have to go in that direction. Other parameters are also measured in the code. An example image of a q-v diagram and a desired velocity distribution resulting from this code are attached.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import norm

# CSV-Datei laden
df = pd.read_csv('Beispiel.csv')

# Entfernen aller Zeilen mit "Speed" über 60 km/h
df = df[df['Speed'] <= 60]
# Kombinieren von Datum und Uhrzeit zu einem datetime-Objekt, explizites Format angeben
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'], format='%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S.%f')

# Setzen Sie 'datetime' als Index für Resampling
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)

# Resample auf 5-Minuten-Intervall und aggregiere die Daten
traffic_data = df.resample('5T').agg({
    'Speed': ['count', lambda x: list(x.dropna())]
})

# Umbenennen der Spalten
traffic_data.columns = ['count', 'speeds']

# Hochkalkulation der Verkehrsstärke auf Stunden
traffic_data['count_hourly'] = traffic_data['count'] * 12  # 12 * 5-Minuten Intervalle pro Stunde

# Berechnung der QV-Verteilung
qv_data = []
for _, row in traffic_data.iterrows():
    count_hourly = row['count_hourly']
    speeds = row['speeds']
    if len(speeds) > 0:
        speeds_sorted = sorted(speeds)
        for speed in speeds_sorted:
            qv_data.append({'count_hourly': count_hourly, 'speed': speed})

qv_df = pd.DataFrame(qv_data)
# Berechnung der statistischen Kennzahlen über alle Daten
speeds = df['Speed'].dropna()

# Berechnung der mittleren Geschwindigkeit, Standardabweichung, V50- und V85-Geschwindigkeit
mean_speed = np.mean(speeds)
std_dev = np.std(speeds)
v50_speed = np.percentile(speeds, 50)
v85_speed = np.percentile(speeds, 85)

# Ausgabe der berechneten Werte
print(f"Mittlere Geschwindigkeit: {mean_speed:.2f} km/h")
print(f"Standardabweichung: {std_dev:.2f} km/h")
print(f"V50-Geschwindigkeit: {v50_speed:.2f} km/h")
print(f"V85-Geschwindigkeit: {v85_speed:.2f} km/h")

# Berechnung des unbeeinflussten Anteils basierend auf "Time gap"
unbeeinflusst = df[df['Time gap'] >= 4.0]
beeinflusst = df[df['Time gap'] < 4.0]

# Berechnung der Wunschgeschwindigkeit basierend auf der Wurzelfunktion
def sqrt_model(q, c, d):
    return c * np.sqrt(q) + d

# Anpassung der Wurzelfunktion
q_values = qv_df['count_hourly']
v_values = qv_df['speed']
# Schätzung der Parameter für die Wurzelfunktion
params_sqrt, _ = curve_fit(sqrt_model, q_values, v_values)
c, d = params_sqrt
V0 = d
print(f"Wunschgeschwindigkeit V0 (Wurzelfunktion Modell): {V0:.2f} km/h")

# Schätzung der Normalverteilung der Wunschgeschwindigkeit mit MLE
def mle_normal_distribution(v_values):
    mu_mle = np.mean(v_values)
    sigma_mle = np.std(v_values)
    return mu_mle, sigma_mle

# Berechnung der Wunschgeschwindigkeit aus der Wurzelfunktion
q_values_for_mle = np.array(qv_df['count_hourly'])
v_values_from_sqrt_model = sqrt_model(q_values_for_mle, *params_sqrt)

# MLE-Schätzung für Wunschgeschwindigkeitsverteilung
mu_wunsch, sigma_wunsch = mle_normal_distribution(v_values_from_sqrt_model)
print(f"MLE-Mittelwert der Wunschgeschwindigkeit: {mu_wunsch:.2f} km/h")
print(f"MLE-Standardabweichung der Wunschgeschwindigkeit: {sigma_wunsch:.2f} km/h")

# Normalverteilung der unbeeinflussten Fahrzeuge
speeds_unbeeinflusst = unbeeinflusst['Speed'].dropna()
mu_unbeeinflusst = np.mean(speeds_unbeeinflusst)
sigma_unbeeinflusst = np.std(speeds_unbeeinflusst)

# Ergebnisse anzeigen
print(f"Mittelwert der unbeeinflussten Kfz (mu): {mu_unbeeinflusst:.2f} km/h")
print(f"Standardabweichung der unbeeinflussten Kfz (sigma): {sigma_unbeeinflusst:.2f} km/h")
# Plot der Verteilungsfunktionen
speeds_sorted = np.sort(np.concatenate((v_values_from_sqrt_model, speeds_unbeeinflusst)))
fw_v_all = norm.cdf(speeds_sorted, loc=mu_wunsch, scale=sigma_wunsch)
fw_v_unbeeinflusst = norm.cdf(speeds_sorted, loc=mu_unbeeinflusst, scale=sigma_unbeeinflusst)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(speeds_sorted, fw_v_all, 'b-', label='Wunschgeschwindigkeitsverteilung (MLE)')
plt.plot(speeds_sorted, fw_v_unbeeinflusst, 'r-', label='unbeeinflusste Kfz')
plt.xlabel('v [km/h]')
plt.ylabel('FW(v) [-]')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(0, 80)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Vergleich der Wunschgeschwindigkeit V0 mit dem Mittelwert der Verteilung der unbeeinflussten Kfz
print(f"Vergleich der Wunschgeschwindigkeit V0 ({V0:.2f} km/h) mit dem Mittelwert der unbeeinflussten Kfz (mu): {mu_unbeeinflusst:.2f} km/h")

# q-v-Diagramm plotten
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.scatter(q_values, v_values, alpha=0.3, s=8)
plt.xlabel('q [Kfz/h]')
plt.ylabel('v [km/h]')
plt.xlim(0, 800)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


enter image description here
enter image description here
